# Portable Python interpreter for Windows 7

Tags: python, software-development, programming, scripting

Please recommend a Python interpreter with a few specific requirements:

1. Portable (no writing to the Windows registry or creating/modifying files outside of its own folder/subfolders)
2. Gratis for personal use
3. Compatible with Windows 7
4. As up-to-date release of Python as possible

I don't need a fancy IDE or anything.  CLI is preferred, but GUI is fine too.

Here's what I've looked at:

1. [Python Windows Embeddable Package 64-bit v3.8.8](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) - This isn't great, because it is an older version of Python that has known security issues and bugs.  Their latest release is incompatible with Windows 7.  Also, the code I'm trying to run isn't working on it (for the code I'm trying to run, see [this QA](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233140/exporting-call-records-with-phone-call-recordings-from-mega-call-recorder-advanc/233968)).
2. [virtualenv PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) - This looks tempting, but it has more learning curve than I have time for right now.
3. [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) - Also tempting, but none of their releases are current, and their is no indication I could find regarding which releases are compatible with Windows 7.
4. [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/open-source) - Clever name. I have only been able to find installer releases of this, and not any portable packages.  Also, their versions are a bit out of date.
5. [Python-XY](https://python-xy.github.io/) - Very outdated Python releases.
6. [Portable Python](https://portablepython.com/) - This project has been discontinued.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I feel as if you were born to answer this question! :)

Comment: Anaconda is easy to keep up to date. that is one of its strengths. It's what I recommend, but I have no idea about whether it qualifies as portable  on Windows 7 since I use a Mac.

Comment: @EricS Thanks Eric.  Anaconda was recommended to me by someone offline, and it's great to hear your positive experiences with it too.  I was told that it is portable or has a portable version, but I haven't found any documentation of that yet.